# What it means to use the default lifecycle in Maven

Tags: java, maven

As per [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), the doc explains as below for default lifecycle:

> These lifecycle phases (plus the other lifecycle phases not shown
>   here) are executed sequentially to complete the default lifecycle.
>   Given the lifecycle phases above, this means that **when the default
>   lifecycle is used**, Maven will first validate the project, then will
>   try to compile the sources, run those against the tests, package the
>   binaries (e.g. jar), run integration tests against that package,
>   verify the package, install the verifed package to the local
>   repository, then deploy the installed package in a specified
>   environment.

What it means to use a default lifecycle? Is there any command to use it.

**Update:**

This question is different from the question which I posted earlier - [What is the default lifecycle in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716406/what-is-the-default-lifecycle-in-maven)

Earlier question is on what is the default lifecycle in Maven.

Now the question is to understand how to use the default lifecycle? Is there any specific command to run the default lifecycle without specifying any phase of the default lifecycle.

Comment: @V_Singh, I only asked that question, that was to understand what does it mean when we say default lifecycle. Now the question is to know is there any specific command to use it when the doc says - " when the default lifecycle is used."

Comment: Even if it's not a duplicate, it's not very clear what you are after here: "a specific command to run the default lifecylce without specifying any phase of the default lifecycle"? What does that even mean? A lifecycle in maven is a succession of phases. A maven command typically consists of specifying one of those phases as a goal. So why would you expect/want to be able to use the default lifecycle _without_ specifying one of its phases? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a bit further in the document you linked - down to [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) - you see three lifecycles **clean**, **default** and **site** and their respective build phases.

The default lifecycle is used whenever you invoke `mvn` with one of its phases as argument. If you invoke `mvn test`, for instance, Maven goes through all of the default lifecycle's phases up to and including `test` in the order stated there.